# setFromObject(mesh) returns wrong values, sometimes

Tags: javascript, three.js, bounding-box

*`THREE.Box3.setFromObject(*object*)` returns wrong values. The best way to show you is by showing you how I work through it:*

I create 2 meshes from vertices. First one with the `triangle()` function, the other with `trapezoidForm()`.

```
var triangle = function (base, height) {

    return [
        new THREE.Vector2(0,  -height / 2),
        new THREE.Vector2(-base / 2,  height / 2),
        new THREE.Vector2(base / 2,  height / 2)
    ];
}
var trapezoidForm = function (base, upperBase, height) {

    return [

        new THREE.Vector2(-base / 2,  height / 2),
        new THREE.Vector2(-upperBase / 2,  -height / 2),
        new THREE.Vector2(upperBase / 2,  -height / 2),
        new THREE.Vector2(base / 2,  height / 2),
    ];

}
```

I use the returned value to create my mesh:

```
var material    = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x666666, /*specular: 0x101010*//*, shininess: 200*/ });
var shape       = new THREE.Shape(vertices);
var mesh        = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape), material);
```

And use that to place it in the scene, and to create a boundingbox:

```
mesh.position.set(posX, 0, posZ);
mesh.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
boundingBox.setFromObject(mesh);
```

Now, I want to find the center of my 2 shapes. Easy enough: I take the boundingbox, and calculate it. Like this:

```
var centerX = (boundingBox.max.x + boundingBox.min.x) * 0.5;
var centerZ = (boundingBox.max.z + boundingBox.min.z) * 0.5;
```

Here is where it goes wrong: For the triangle, it calculates the right spot, but for the trapezoid, it messes up.

Below is a printscreen of the console. The first 3 vertices are for the triangle, followed by the boundingbox. The next 4 are for the trapezoid, with again the bounding box. For the vertices: first number is X-coord, second one is Z-coord.

[image: Console log, showing the problem]

Desired result: 2nd boundingbox should return something like:

```
max: X: 200
     Z: 200

min: X: -200
     Z: -100
```

Image showing the current state (triangle has the minus-sign in the middle, trapezoid not):

[image: state of situation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself in the end:

I have to create my boundingBox before I reposition or rotate it:

```
//Boundingbox
boundingBox.setFromObject(mesh);

mesh.position.set(posX, 0, posZ);
mesh.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
```

instead of:

```
mesh.position.set(posX, 0, posZ);
mesh.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
//Boundingbox
boundingBox.setFromObject(mesh);
```

the reason why the triangle didn't cause problems, was because it was rendered on 0,0.